# If i have an empty arraylist, can i add an element in any position or do i have to start off with the 0 index?

Tags: java, arrays

I have used this code but i am getting an INdexOutOfBoundsException

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();

list1.add(7,"A");
```

Comment: [Add(int index, E element)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-) says that you cannot add an element greater than the size of array. So I guess it is not correct to say that you can insert at any point. 

Let's say you have array of size n. add will allow you to insert at any point from 0 to n. n+1 and so on will through an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in the way you try to do it. When declaring an `ArrayList`, you only create an object of an `ArrayList`. It has no size or default value. You can think about mentioning the size attribute as `ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(8);`. But that is the limitation of creating indexes. Even this `ArrayList` has no default value. You have to store data one by one from index 0. You can try this way to get your output.

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
list1.add(0,null);
list1.add(1,null);
list1.add(2,null);
list1.add(3,null);
list1.add(4,null);
list1.add(5,null);
list1.add(6,null);
list1.add(7,"A");
```

or using for loop,

```
ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i=0; i<=6; i++) {
    list1.add(i,null);
}
list1.add(7,"A");
```